# When moving a selected vertx the whole cube moves

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to model a dino, but when I try to move a selected vertex the whole cube moves.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably enabled the *Proportional Editing* option:

[image]

Comment: no its turned off

Comment: so please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/7b5a514fac114681ad6f30f099f31b36

Comment: mmh that's weird because everything works fine here. Of course when you move a vertex, its mirrored version also moves but it's because you have a Mirror modifier...

Comment: I want to make it like when you move a vretx the cube doesn't change.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, could you be more precise please?

Comment: Like when a vertx moves the other faces don't flop around.Only one face.

Comment: sorry I don't really know how to explain.

Comment: maybe edit your question in order to give more explanations, show pictures etc

Comment: https://ibb.co/S3NthjC

Comment: not like in the pic

Comment: like not moving a whole face

Comment: it's still not clear I'm sorry  ;)  I hope someone will understand... if you move an empty the face will be deformed of course

Comment: is tere a way to make the vertx behind the selected vertx movewhen you move the selected vertx?

Comment: what vertex? move how? You should follow some basic tutorials because it's a bit hard to answer    ;)